# HTML zoom & lightbox

Tags: jquery, html, css

i would zooming and showing image witn lightbox.

Example is in this link :

http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples

İn the site go to the partision named gallery & lightbox.

I've tried the code but it did not work.

Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="gal1">

  <a href="#" data-image="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/small/image1.png" data-zoom-image="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/small/image1.png">
    <img id="img_01" src="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/small/image1.png" />
  </a>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    //initiate the plugin and pass the id of the div containing gallery images
$("#zoom_03").elevateZoom({gallery:'gallery_01', cursor: 'pointer', galleryActiveClass: 'active', imageCrossfade: true, loadingIcon: 'http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/spinner.gif'}); 

//pass the images to Fancybox
$("#zoom_03").bind("click", function(e) {  
  var ez =   $('#zoom_03').data('elevateZoom'); 
    $.fancybox(ez.getGalleryList());
  return false;
});

</script>

<style type="text/css">

    /*set a border on the images to prevent shifting*/
 #gallery_01 img{border:2px solid white;}

 /*Change the colour*/
 .active img{border:2px solid #333 !important;}

</style>

</body>
</html>
```

Help please.

Not : I don't have a good English. Pardon me. I hope you understand.

Comment: What code have you tried? Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. Please help us help you by showing us what you've tried and specific problems you've encountered.

Comment: Can we see your full code? We can't help if we don't see any code. Make sure you're including all JS files and css files..

Comment: have you use this code $("#zoom_01").elevateZoom();For elevateZoom you need to include java script and css file

Comment: @LambdaNinja i added a code

Comment: @Timothy i added a code

Comment: Your JavaScript references an element with the ID of "zoom_03". I don't see that element in your HTML.

Comment: @showdev i copied from the site

Comment: @showdev what should i change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ElevateZoom example looks flawed. The code displayed seems to have errors, like duplicate IDs in the HTML and non-existent IDs referenced in the JavaScript, and doesn't seem to match the code being executed in the demo. Not sure what's going on there.

Mainly, the ID you're using to initiate ElevateZoom doesn't exist in your HTML code. In my example below, I store the "gallery" element in a variable for later use so that I only need to specify that ID once.

I couldn't get the ElevateZoom code to work with the recent version of FancyBox. The object provided by ElevateZoom seems not to be formatted correctly for FancyBox, so I rewrote that part.

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  // define the gallery object
  var $gallery = $('#gallery_01');

  // Build array of objects to open in Fancybox.
  var $imgs = [];
  $('a', $gallery).each(function() {
    $imgs.push({'src': $(this).data('zoom-image')});
  });

  // Initiate ElevateZoom
  $("#zoom").elevateZoom({
    gallery: $gallery.attr('id'),
    cursor: 'pointer',
    galleryActiveClass: 'active',
    imageCrossfade: true,
    loadingIcon: '//www.elevateweb.co.uk/spinner.gif'
  });

  // Bind Fancybox to clicking the zoom image.
  // Open it to the currently active index.
  $("#zoom").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var active_index = $('a.active', $gallery).index();
    $.fancybox.open($imgs, false, active_index);
  });

});
```

```css
#gallery_01 img {
  border: 2px solid white;
  width: 96px;
}

#gallery_01 .active img {
  border: 2px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/elevatezoom/3.0.8/jquery.elevatezoom.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.1.25/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.1.25/jquery.fancybox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<img id="zoom" src="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/small/image1.png" data-zoom-image="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/large/image1.jpg" width="411">

<div id="gallery_01">

  <a href="#" class="elevatezoom-gallery active" data-image="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/small/image1.png" data-zoom-image="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/large/image1.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/small/image1.png" width="100"></a>

  <a href="#" class="elevatezoom-gallery" data-image="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/small/image2.png" data-zoom-image="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/large/image2.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/small/image2.png" width="100"></a>

  <a href="#" class="elevatezoom-gallery" data-image="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/small/image3.png" data-zoom-image="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/large/image3.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/small/image3.png" width="100"></a>

  <a href="#" class="elevatezoom-gallery" data-image="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/small/image4.png" data-zoom-image="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/large/image4.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/small/image4.png" width="100"></a>

</div>
```

Comment: İf i use this extensions in a commerce sites does cause problem?

Comment: @Thiers Not directly. What sort of problem are you anticipating?

Comment: licanse problems?

Comment: @Theirs I'd say it's worth reviewing the license for any third-party script, especially for use on a commercial site. For Fancybox, "[commercial license is required for all commercial applications](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/#license)". ElevateZoom appears to be "[licensed under the GPL and MIT licenses](https://github.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom/blob/master/README.md#license)".

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full working code. Try to learn from this! :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'/>
<title></title>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/jquery.fancybox.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/jquery.elevatezoom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/jquery.fancybox.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>


<div class="zoom-wrapper">
    <div class="zoom-left">

<div style="height:274px;width:411px;" class="zoomWrapper"><img style="border: 1px solid rgb(232, 232, 230); position: absolute;" id="zoom_03" src="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/small/image3.png" data-zoom-image="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/large/image3.jpg" width="411">
</div>

        <div id="gallery_01" style="width:500px">

        <a href="#" class="elevatezoom-gallery active" data-update="" data-image="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/small/image1.png" data-zoom-image="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/large/image1.jpg">
        <img src="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/small/image1.png" width="100"></a>

        <a href="#" class="elevatezoom-gallery" data-image="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/small/image2.png" data-zoom-image="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/large/image2.jpg"><img src="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/small/image2.png" width="100"></a>

        <a href="tester" class="elevatezoom-gallery" data-image="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/small/image3.png" data-zoom-image="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/large/image3.jpg">
             <img src="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/small/image3.png" width="100">
        </a>

        <a href="tester" class="elevatezoom-gallery" data-image="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/small/image4.png" data-zoom-image="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/large/image4.jpg"><img src="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/small/image4.png" width="100"></a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#zoom_03").elevateZoom({gallery:'gallery_01', cursor: 'pointer', galleryActiveClass: "active",
    imageCrossfade: true,loadingIcon: "loading.gif"}); 

$("#zoom_03").bind("click", function(e) {  
    var ez =   $('#zoom_03').data('elevateZoom');
    ez.closeAll(); //NEW: This function force hides the lens, tint and window   
        $.fancybox(ez.getGalleryList());
        return false;
    }); 
}); 
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$('#zoom_01').elevateZoom({
    zoomType: "inner",
    cursor: "crosshair",
    zoomWindowFadeIn: 500,
    zoomWindowFadeOut: 750
}); 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```